# R - Spectral Clustering for Glass data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying Spectral Clustering on Glass dataset from UCI repository. If you know Glass data has 9 attributes `"RI"`, `"Na"`, `"Mg"`, `"Al"`, `"Si"`, `"K"`, `"Ca"`, `"Ba"`, and `"Fe"`. I am using `"kknn"` package which has spectral clustering "specClust", as following to obtain results:

```
library(kknn)
data(glass)
specClust(glass[, 1:9], centers=2, nn=50, iter.max=30)
```

However, in result, I am getting cluster means for 2 attributes, as following:

```
     [,1]       [,2]
1  0.9096567 -0.3331058
2  0.5101274  0.8273862
```

It should supposed to return cluster means for all 9 attributes not just for 2. When I am running K-means clustering, R console is returning cluster means for 9 attributes, as following:

```
       RI      Na       Mg       Al       Si         K        Ca     Ba
1  1.519226 13.7124 0.210400 1.837800 72.87120 0.4910000 10.160400 0.56580000
2  1.518103 13.3150 3.438841 1.325122 72.58378 0.4989024  8.590061 0.05591463
      Fe
1  0.0480000
2  0.0597561
```

I would like to know why Spectral Clustering in `"kknn"` package is returning cluster means for only 2 attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were looking at the statistics for the 2 clusters overall.

This should give you what you were looking for and more:

```
pacman::p_load(kknn)
data(glass)
cl   <- specClust(glass[, 1:9], centers=2, nn=50, iter.max=30) 
pcol <- as.character(glass$Type)
pairs(glass[2:10], pch = pcol, col = c("green", "red")[cl$cluster])
table(glass$Type, cl$cluster)

aggregate(glass[,2:10],by=list(cl$cluster),mean)
```

> ```
>   Group.1       RI       Na        Mg       Al      Si         K       Ca          Ba         Fe
> 1       1 1.519061 13.81638 0.9115942 1.746232 72.6613 0.4652174 9.729130 0.534202899 0.04318841
> 2       2 1.518035 13.21345 3.5282069 1.301517 72.6460 0.5122069 8.589517 0.004137931 0.06358621
> ```

[image]